# MVVM + Mediator pattern: Registration of Mediator occurs too late

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mediator

I have tried to implement Mediator Pattern in WPF/MVVM app to make possible the communication between ViewModels.

To apply mediator pattern I downloaded a sample project from [this link](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/03/20/more-than-just-mvc-for-wpf/). And then I learned it from the sample and then I applied to my Sample Project.

I have got some problems with the usage of this pattern which in-turn produces ridiculous output.

Let me start this with my code:

**Here is my project Structure:**

```
SampleWPFMVVMMediatorApp
|
|--Data
|  |--MenuItems.xml
|
|--Extensions
|  |--MediatorX
|  |  |--IColleague.cs
|  |  |--Mediator.cs
|  |  |--Messages.cs
|  |  |--MultiDictionary.cs
|  |--ViewModelBase.cs
|
|--Models
|  |--MenuItem.cs
|
|--ViewModels
|  |--MainWindowViewModel.cs
|  |--ParentMenuViewModel.cs
|  |--ChildMenuViewModel.cs
|  |--SamplePageViewModel.cs
|
|--Views
|  |--ParentMenuView.xaml
|  |--ChildMenuView.xaml
|  |--SamplePage.xaml
|
|--App.xaml
|--MainWindow.xaml
```

**Code:**

I will just post the code for ViewModels and Models to shorten the length of the question.

*MenuItem.cs*

```
public class MenuItem 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*MainWindowViewModel.cs*

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Mediator.Register(this, new[] { Messages.SelectedParentMenuItem, Messages.SelectedChildMenuItem });
    }

    private string _sourcePage;
    public string SourcePage
    {
        get
        {
            return _sourcePage;
        }
        set
        {
            _sourcePage = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SourcePage");
        }
    }

    private MenuItem _currentParentMenuItem;
    public MenuItem CurrentParentMenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentParentMenuItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentParentMenuItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentParentMenuItem");
        }
    }

    private MenuItem _currentChildMenuItem;
    public MenuItem CurrentChildMenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentChildMenuItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentChildMenuItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentChildMenuItem");

            if (CurrentChildMenuItem != null)
            {
                SourcePage = (from menuItem in XDocument.Load(Messages.DataDirectory + "MenuItems.xml")
                                                        .Element("MenuItems").Elements("MenuItem").Elements("MenuItem")
                              where (int)menuItem.Parent.Attribute("Id") == CurrentParentMenuItem.Id &&
                                    (int)menuItem.Attribute("Id") == CurrentChildMenuItem.Id
                              select menuItem.Element("SourcePage").Value).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }
    }

    public override void MessageNotification(string message, object args)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
            case Messages.SelectedParentMenuItem:
                CurrentParentMenuItem = (MenuItem)args;
                break;
            case Messages.SelectedChildMenuItem:
                CurrentChildMenuItem = (MenuItem)args;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

*ParentMenuViewModel.cs*

```
public class ParentMenuViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ParentMenuViewModel()
    {
        ParentMenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>(
                                                                from menuItem in XDocument.Load(Messages.DataDirectory + "MenuItems.xml")
                                                                                          .Element("MenuItems").Elements("MenuItem")
                                                                select new MenuItem
                                                                {
                                                                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(menuItem.Attribute("Id").Value),
                                                                    Name = menuItem.Element("Name").Value
                                                                }
                                                            );
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> _parentMenuItems;
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> ParentMenuItems
    {
        get
        {
            return _parentMenuItems;
        }
        set
        {
            _parentMenuItems = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ParentMenuItems");
        }
    }

    private MenuItem _selectedParentMenuItem;
    public MenuItem SelectedParentMenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedParentMenuItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedParentMenuItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedParentMenuItem");

            Mediator.NotifyColleagues(Messages.SelectedParentMenuItem, SelectedParentMenuItem);
        }
    }

    public override void MessageNotification(string message, object args)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

*ChildMenuViewModel.cs*

```
public class ChildMenuViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ChildMenuViewModel()
    {
        Mediator.Register(this, new[] { Messages.SelectedParentMenuItem });
    }

    private MenuItem _currentParentMenuItem;
    public MenuItem CurrentParentMenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentParentMenuItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentParentMenuItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentParentMenuItem");

            ChildMenuItemsOfSelectedParent
                    = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>(
                                                            from menuItem in XDocument.Load(Messages.DataDirectory + "MenuItems.xml")
                                                                                      .Element("MenuItems").Elements("MenuItem").Elements("MenuItem")
                                                            where (int)menuItem.Parent.Attribute("Id") == CurrentParentMenuItem.Id
                                                            select new MenuItem
                                                            {
                                                                Id = Convert.ToInt32(menuItem.Attribute("Id").Value),
                                                                Name = menuItem.Element("Name").Value,
                                                            }
                                                        );

        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> _childMenuItemsOfSelectedParent;
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> ChildMenuItemsOfSelectedParent
    {
        get
        {
            return _childMenuItemsOfSelectedParent;
        }
        set
        {
            _childMenuItemsOfSelectedParent = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ChildMenuItemsOfSelectedParent");
        }
    }

    private MenuItem _selectedChildMenuItem;
    public MenuItem SelectedChildMenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedChildMenuItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedChildMenuItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedChildMenuItem");

            Mediator.NotifyColleagues(Messages.SelectedChildMenuItem, SelectedChildMenuItem);
        }
    }

    public override void MessageNotification(string message, object args)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
            case Messages.SelectedParentMenuItem:
                CurrentParentMenuItem = (MenuItem)args;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

*SamplePageViewModel.cs*

```
public class SamplePageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SamplePageViewModel()
    {
        Mediator.Register(this, new[] { Messages.SelectedChildMenuItem });
    }

    private MenuItem _currentChildMenuItem;
    public MenuItem CurrentChildMenuItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentChildMenuItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _currentChildMenuItem = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CurrentChildMenuItem");
        }
    }

    public override void MessageNotification(string message, object args)
    {
        switch (message)
        {
            case Messages.SelectedChildMenuItem:
                CurrentChildMenuItem = (MenuItem)args;
                break;
        }
    }
```

**Sample:**

You can download the sample project that I have created [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0bZFlBaGpzZXU5OXc/edit?usp=sharing).

**Problem:**

Please download the sample project by clicking on the link mentioned in above line to clearly understand my problem.

1. Run the application.
2. As you might expect the ChildMenuView to display some items, it does not show anything initially. I think this problem occurs because ParentMenuView notifies that selectedParentMenuItem is changed before the ChildMenuView Registers itself.
3. When you select any other ParentMenuItem, the ChildMenuView gets some data and it displays it correctly.
4. Click on any childMenuItem, you might expect to see a page loaded and some text on the Frame. But that does not display anything. Here also I think the same problem that I mentioned in step2.
5. Click on any other ChildMenuItem. This time Frame should display some data and then app works as expected.

So, my question is How to notify a property that Registers itself after another property has called NotifyColleagues?

Comment: Your question is way too long, and will probably not get an answer in its current form. Try to summarize and include only the relevant information. Nobody is going to read your question if it takes more than 1 or 2 minutes...

Comment: seems like the project is bit over complicated, I am wondering why would you need a custom mediator when you have bindings?

Comment: @pushpraj can you explain me further?

Comment: wpf's binding provide a mechanism for communication between objects  in a loosely coupled manner. primary purpose of mediator is also same. so my concern is to know the purpose of introducing mediator with wpf. since it has introduced code duplication and extra synchronization. if necessary you may prefer to choose [Service locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) instead of mediator.

Comment: @pushpraj still i am not getting you. How a binding can be used to communicate between objects? If you get time then please refector my sample project,  which will make me some sense.

Comment: the conclusion I made is after trying the sample project included in the question. in the mean time you may have a look on [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) and see if this can be your mediator.

Comment: @pushpraj I have read the full article in the past and now also I refered it on your recommendation. But still I can not find a way to communicate between Objects.

Comment: you may perhaps want to read [Everything you wanted to know about databinding in WPF](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/04/05/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-one.html)

Comment: @Vishal *which* objects, and communicate *how*?

Comment: @Mashton I would like my viewModels to communicate with each-other.

Comment: @pushpraj I did not find anything to communicate between viewModels in series of that 5 posts that you suggested.

Comment: never mind, I'll try to re-write your code with binding to demonstrate the same. may that helps to solve your issue without adding the redundant mediator. do please expect the same by tomorrow, it's quite late today.

Comment: @pushpraj Thanks. I will wait for your reply and if I get anything before your reply then I will post it here.

Comment: I did try to re-write some of the code to show how the properties can be accessed in different views, and also implemented a sample of service locator to have a look. download [SampleWPFMVVMMediatorApp.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2f5wPS0jKJPNXFoc2o4SGhldHc/view) for the same.

Comment: @pushpraj I have took a look at your solution. It works fine. But there I find two problems. 1) ViewModels are tightly-coupled as MainWindowViewModel holds a reference to other ViewModels. 2) I cannot reuse Views as their selectedItem property resides in MainWindowViewModel.

Comment: the code adjustment I did is just a sample around your existing code. if I have to write the same from scratch I would have wrote it differently. secondly some degree of tight coupling between view models is acceptable, however tight coupling between views ad view models should be avoided. decoupling comes with a cost, so just see if the effort is worth investing.

Comment: @pushpraj I appreciate your efforts but still I am not fully satisfied with your answer. I will wait for any other solution and then if I did not find any other solution, then I will accept your solution.

Comment: great! in the meanwhile I'll also try to re-write the same from scratch in more decoupled way.

Comment: @pushpraj Thank you, for a great helping hand :)

Comment: @pushpraj Thanks for your help. I have got a preety good solution. Have a look at it and enjoy!!!! I can have now loosely coupled viewModels..... Hurray!!!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find my updated version of your App [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Z3HglEd6P0Z3c0VWs2WmFINEk/edit?usp=sharing).

`<Rant>`To me, the mediator pattern is just a way of not having to structure your code correctly, and I've never used it in my real code scenarios. Your demo application is a prime example where creating a collection of submodels on your ViewModel (e.g. `ObservableCollection<ChildMenuViewModel>` on `ParentMenuViewModel`) makes perfect sense. By contrast, monitoring a property on the parent ViewModel from the (not even yet existing) child ViewModel seems like shooting yourself in the foot. Instead of the nice hierarchy it could be, it's a cacophony of everyone broadcasting.`</Rant>`.

If you really want to stay inside that pattern, you need to make sure your object is registered to the Mediator (as you've noticed in your question already) before it's supposed to catch the Mediator notification.

In the case of the Parent/ChildMenu this is easy, just rearrange MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <!-- ColumnDefinitions omitted -->
    <views:ChildMenuView Grid.Column="0" />
    <Frame Grid.Column="1" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Content="{Binding SourcePage}"/>
</Grid>

<views:ParentMenuView Grid.Row="0" />
```

For the Frame however, it's much more complicated, because the content is instantiated dynamically (simplified: by setting the URI in the setter of the SelectedChildMenuItem). So you would need for the BindingEngine to finish updating the URI, for the Frame content to load, and only *then* raise your `NotifyColleagues(SelectedChildMenuItem)` call. This is really getting ugly... There is a workaround for everything, of course, and you can circumnavigate the worst by changing your Frame setup, binding the `Content` (see above) instead of the `Source` and instantiating the Content (`SamplePage`) before making the NotifyColleagues call:

```
private MenuItem _selectedChildMenuItem;
public MenuItem SelectedChildMenuItem
{
    get { return _selectedChildMenuItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectedChildMenuItem = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedChildMenuItem");

        LoadSourcePage(); // first instantiate the page (register it to mediator)
        Mediator.NotifyColleagues(Messages.SelectedChildMenuItem, SelectedChildMenuItem); // only now notify
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the SourcePage and pass it to MainWindowViewModel
/// </summary>
private void LoadSourcePage()
{
    if (SelectedChildMenuItem != null)
    {
        var sourceUri = (from menuItem in XDocument.Load(Messages.DataDirectory + "MenuItems.xml")
                                                .Element("MenuItems").Elements("MenuItem").Elements("MenuItem")
                            where (int)menuItem.Parent.Attribute("Id") == CurrentParentMenuItem.Id &&
                                (int)menuItem.Attribute("Id") == SelectedChildMenuItem.Id
                            select menuItem.Element("SourcePage").Value).FirstOrDefault();

        var relativePart = sourceUri.Substring(sourceUri.IndexOf(",,,") + 3);

        var sourcePage = System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(new Uri(relativePart, UriKind.Relative)); // instantiation with URI
        Mediator.NotifyColleagues(Messages.SourcePage, sourcePage); // pass on
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent stuff! It works now as expected. I have tested it on my real project as well. And it works fine upto now. I have accepted the answer and will award the bounty after 24 hours as per the rules of stackoverflow.com

Comment: If you were to create similar project, then what will be your choice? Not the mediator as I guess. Can you provide an example of how would you create it?

Comment: Since you're asking nicely... [MenuDemo.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzwIjbsR-mOyYUs1WGRfVkFiRE0/edit?usp=sharing). The only thing that was a bit tricky is to pass the DataContext into the Frame content. Notice that the only real code left is loading the menu from xml (once, instead of at every selection change). Horizontal/VerticalMenu controls replace ChildMenuView/ParentMenuView (I try not to have multiple views on one control, instead I have multiple controls on one view). Did this help, do you have objections?